# Installing Magento using Xamp on Ubuntu gives this error

Tags: installation

I installed Xamp and in htdocs I created a folder named magento. I unpacked the magento installer into the folder named magento.

When I start the sever and go to `localhost/magento` I get this error:

```
Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

How do I fix it ?
I tried following the instructions here in the SO query below and it didn't work.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/604522/install-composer-and-configure-with-xampp

Thank you!

Comment: run `composer update` command

Comment: when I run composer it shows that it is installed but when I run any command including "update" I get :  "composer info
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/wktdev
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section"    I will follow the instructions in that message but I figure I would mention it regardless.

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions and it made it worse. Now my machine can't find "composer" when I run it.   :(

Comment: @MohitPatel when I do composer update I get a prompt asking for my magento credentials. I went to magento to create them. When I run update composer and type my credentials it does not work. I tried doing it by resetting my password twice thinking it was my fault. Their is something wrong and I don't know how to fix it. Here is an image link. https://i.imgur.com/6yDeXtt.png

Comment: You're using your magento account details. Wrong thing. You need to create a public and private key pair in the profile/account section of the magento marketplace. Last time I used it you had to log in, go to the marketplace then access the account or profile section (I can't remember what they called it) and then find the option to create the keys. Public key is the username private key is the password

Comment: hi william if you suceed in installing magento on xampp kindly post your solution here as am trying for weeks on lamp and got stuck everytime at some point.